# Inconsistent total count for Elasticsearch phrase_prefix match query

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch cluster with 2 nodes, each node containing a total of 10 shards (5 primary, 5 replica). Both the nodes are in sync with each other.

When we execute a phrase_prefix match query (similar to the one mentioned below) multiple times, we get up to 4 different total hits in the response.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "field.subfield": {
                  "query": "11",
                  "type": "phrase_prefix"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is no special mapping for the field we are querying, it is just a string.

I'm trying to figure out why the total hits would vary, without any changes in the index. Is there something obvious that I have missed?

Any ideas about why this could happen?

Cheers.

Comment: This can happen in a split brain situation (when cluster nodes cannot see each other via the transport service/9300).  Checking the cluster health of each node directly will let you verify that each node knows it's part of  the full 2-node cluster.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/cluster-health.html

Comment: @PeterDixon-Moses I've verified that the nodes know about each other, doesn't look like that is the issue.